# Poisson Distribution with Drawing Balls

Tags: probability, probability-theory, poisson-distribution

If two series of $100$ draws are made from a box at random. The box has $1000$ balls where there are $2$ black balls and the rest are all white. What is the probability that they both produce the same amount of black balls?

I want to use a Poisson Distribution here, however I don't know how to start.

Comment: All I want to know is whether or not I would use $\mu = 5$ or $\mu = 2$ and why?

Comment: This isn't a Poisson distribution; rather, you want the hypergeometric distribution.

Comment: @dmk I am required to use a Poisson distribution though. But, how would the hypergeometric distribution work here? I would still like to see.

Comment: Chance of a black ball on each draw is $2/1000$ (a 'rare event'). There are 100 draws so the mean of an approximating Poisson random variable is 0.2.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem, the number $X$ of black balls drawn is
distributed *approximately* as $POIS(.2)$ and (per the comment of @drnk) has *exactly* the
hypergeometric distribution for 100 draws from a box with 2 black and 998
white balls.

Either way, the random variable $X$ can actually take only values 0, 1 and 2,
and the answer is about 0.7.

Computations in R statistical software:

```
 i = 0:2;  pois.pdf = dpois(i, .2);  hypr.pdf = dhyper(i, 2, 998, 100)
 sum(pois.pdf^2); sum(hypr.pdf^2)
 ## 0.697401
 ## 0.6885172
```

The two distribution tables are as follows (noting that the approximate Poisson
probabilities ignore values greater than 2 and do not add exactly to 1).

```
 cbind(i, pois.pdf, hypr.pdf)
      i   pois.pdf   hypr.pdf
  ##  0 0.81873075 0.80990991
  ##  1 0.16374615 0.18018018
  ##  2 0.01637462 0.00990991

 sum(pois.pdf)
 ## 0.9988515  # not exactly 1
```